# Does this speed numbers show I can improve my internet connection?

Tags: performance, internet-connection, adsl, internet-speed

I have a... quite slow Internet connection, but some weeks ago to now I'm experiencing signs that lead me to believe that maybe my Internet connection is faster than I'm experiencing day to day.

My actual download speed (when I download in the browser and see the speed) is: 30-40 Kb/s (yeah, is very slow). For browsing I think is the same... And upload can be the same or quite less.

But, I made recently (yesterday) an ADSL Test, and the result was: 240Kb/s download, and 140Kb/s upload. And some times the download speed give me peaks of 400Kb/s by 3, 4 or even 5 seconds.

What does that mean? I usually download at 30-40Kb/s as I said, but then why that numbers in the ADSL test and why those peaks when downloading? Those are a sign that my Internet connection can be improve?

Comment: ADSL can conceivably provide multiple megabits of bandwidth, but the actual rate will depend on your provider and your degree of connectedness to them. Also, some servers are fast, and others are slow, so be sure to take your mesaurements when utilizing a well known well provisioned service.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adsl#ADSL_standards

Comment: @FrankThomas my ISP doesn't provide any "speed" reference for the Internet service I'm "hiring"... so I don't know if I can download at a higher speed (for example to those peaks of 400Kb/s) or 30-40Kb/s is the fast I can download... For that reason I'm investigating if I can improve my Internet connection.

Comment: no, there isn;t really anything you can do about that kind of slowness except get another provider. I've had non-DSL based Dialup that was faster than you describe.

Comment: @FrankThomas unfortunatelly that's isn't an option... I'm in Cuba, and my actual ISP is the only ISP in the country, so is impossible to change to other because doesn't exist. Ok. And those 400Kb/s peaks are because?

Comment: for a minute that capacity was available. As I said, ADSL is capable of much faster speeds than 400Kb/s, so the issue isn't the ADSL, but issues within the ISP itself, or issues with the way it connects upstream. Anyway, there is nothing you can do from your position as a customer to optimize or otherwise speed up your connection.

Comment: @FrankThomas Except maybe go live in the Telephone Exchange where the DLSAMs are :)